# Multiselect com filtro de pesquisa

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, front-end

Estou com um problema onde eu tenho uma tabela que possui 12000 registros de tipos e preciso fazer um multi-select em que as opções apareçam de acordo com o filtro de pesquisa do multiselect. O intuito é facilitar o cadastro de itens em uma linha de produção onde, é comum se digitar errado o tipo.

Hoje utilizo o isteven-multi-select porem ao abrir o multi-select a página congela pela quantidade de opções.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm col-md-2">
    <label for="maquina">Partnumber</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
        <isteven-multi-select id="partnumber" class="multiselect form- 
        multiselect" helper-elements="all none filter" 
        translation="traducaoMultiSelect" input-model="partnumber"
        output-model="setupProducaoSelecionados"
        button-label="name"
        item-label="name"
        tick-property="ticked"
        max-labels="4" 
        selection-mode="single"/>
    </div>
</div>

// Obtém todas os Part Numbers do servidor
        restApi.partnumberGerenciamento.query({}, function (array) {
            if (array.length > 0) {
                // Converte para multiselect
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    $scope.partnumber.push({name: array[i].codigo, id: array[i].id});
                    $scope.partnumberCadastro.push({name: array[i].codigo, id: array[i].id});
                }
            }
        }, function (error) {
            mensagem("Erro ao recuperar os Part Numbers.\nCódigo: " + error.status, 'error');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

resolvido trocando

```
'ng-repeat="item in filteredModel | filter:removeGroupEndMarker" class="multiSelectItem"'
```

do arquivo `isteven-multi-select.js` por:

```
'ng-repeat="item in filteredModel | filter:removeGroupEndMarker | limitTo:50" class="multiSelectItem"'
```